# Whats the scala spark equivalent of subset of R

Tags: scala, apache-spark

Assume I have a data frame df in spark, with the structure like so.

**Input:**

```
amount city
10000  la
12145  ng
14000  wy
18000  la
```

How can subset the data frame for amount > 10000

**Expected Output:**

```
amount city
12145  ng
14000  wy
18000  la
```

In R i can do something like this:

```
df1 <- df[df$amount > 10000 ,]
```

I know I can use SQL of spark to do the same, but what is the step which is similar to above

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the docs:

http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/sql-programming-guide.html#untyped-dataset-operations-aka-dataframe-operations

```
val df1 = df.filter($"amount" > 10000)
```